# Barcode Fonts in MS WORD are different

Tags: fonts, ms-word, barcode

I Have googled a lot but do not know the proper way to describe it. not native english

I have made a macro in MS Word that generates a Barcode, very simple and it works. i am not a programmer. For generating the macro you need to have a font installed.

If I install the same font on two different computers i get different results.

I get the following result like in this picture on computer 1

[Result 1](https://d1axv6bfszrjec.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Windows-install-inFlow-Code-39.png)

I get the following result like in this picture on computer 2

[Result 2](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/A-dialog-box-of-the-Barcode-will-appear.jpg?ezimgfmt=ng:webp/ngcb190)

The one is with text beneath the barcode the otherone has not.
but installing the same font on 2 computers i get this different result. i wish to get the barcode without the text beneath.

if anyone has an idea how i should google this  or knows a fix where i need to look please let me know.
it would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Chris

Comment: Without seeing you code and barcode font, no-one can help you with this. In any event, Word has its own barcoding capabilities, implemented via the DISPLAYBARCODE field: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-displaybarcode-6d81eade-762d-4b44-ae81-f9d3d9e07be3 or the MERGEBARCODE field: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-mergebarcode-812fc43f-cb53-4782-8f9f-290ed08d34f3

Comment: I Found an other font that works . Anyway thank you! For looking at my question.